# Getting GoogleApiException when implementing complex query in .NET API

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

When I run this simple query `SELECT * FROM BigQuery.FeePreviewReport LIMIT 100` to retrieve data from google bigquery using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2, it's working fine, but if I run this complex query it's failed to parse it, but in google console, it's working fine.

```
[HttpGet("get")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var results = _bigQueryServices.GetModels<FeePreviewReport>(@"SELECT t.*
                    FROM BigQuery.PreviewReport t
                    WHERE 1 = 1
                    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY ReportstartDate DESC) <= 2");
    return Ok(results);
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

**Google Console:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure your client is set to standard sql, based on error - it is clear  - now it is running in legacy sql. see [Changing from the default dialect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#c)

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant , let me try.

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant now the query is working.

Comment: I just changed, var qr = new QueryRequest() { Query = query,UseLegacySql=false }